# Server hit while inserting the transparent pixel image for tracking

Tags: email, tracking

I'm implementing email tracking feature.

The issue is as soon as I append the image to the body (Just adding the image but not sending), the server hit with the request in the image's src.

Ideally, the server hit should be made only when the email is sent and opened and not when the image is appended to the body.

Please suggest a solution.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Filter your IP out.